# No se encuentra el módulo "./schema" en js

Tags: javascript, typescript, strapi

No se encuentra el módulo `./schema` ni sus declaraciones de tipos correspondientes.

```javascript
'use strict';

const schema = require('./schema');

module.exports = {
  schema,
};
```

Estoy utlizando este código en mi plugin de strapi pero al agregarle el content-type y conectarlo con la API me sale el error.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.